# Using an AWS EC2 LoadBalancer as a Reverse Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, single-page-application, load-balancing

I have an EC2 Loadbalancer that points to a target group on S3. In that S3 bucket is a file index.html that I can request via "http://myserver.com/index.html". Since this is a SPA I need all path to return that file. ie  "http://myserver.com/about" should also return the content of index.html. It should not redirect to that url but really return a http 200 with that content.
I guess its the functionality of a reverse proxy. Can I do this with an EC2 LoadBalancer?

I know that this is usually done with AWS CloudFront, but thats not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point we added a redirect to the Loadbalacer that would redirect a path like myserver.com/about to  myserver.com/?redirectPath=about and then let the Angular app do a navigateByUrl([conten of redirectPath]).

That worked but was also realy bad. We now got the ok for hosting in nginx and everthing is fine.